# How to best troubleshoot apache webserver with lot of requests in "being processed" status

Tags: php, linux, apache, performance, fpm

I am running a Linux Centos/Plesk box with a medium/high traffic Prestahop e-commerce website.

I use the stock-Plesk configuration with PHP 7.0 FPM served by Apache / Nginx as a reverse proxy. I only made some tweaks on FPM pool settings according to the server power basically to increase MaxChildren value to serve more requests.

From some days I am encountering occasional website slowdowns that I am trying to troubleshoot (website did not have any particular visits increases in last time).

I have already performed some checks on:
- server logs, can't see particular error_logs 
- server load average (it is ok)
- I/O "wa" value is OK
- MySQL server has not slow queries during slowdowns (SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST is never returning long execution time queries) 
- net stat (no DDOS / strange connections)

I installed mod_status form Apache and noticed from the server-status page that during slowdowns I have a high number of "requests currently being processed" in "W" status [sending reply] (During slowdowns I can have up to 70/80 of those requests for several seconds) so I can correlate the slowdowns to Apache being busy to deliver requests but I can't figure out why and what application/webpage component is the source of the problem.

My question here is some advice on how to understand the culprit of slowdowns (a PHP script ? a stuck external service during Apache request ?)

thank you.

Comment: Do you have any kind of logging in your application that you can put on?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.